# How to say that two things don't mix well?

Tags: phrase-requests

For example, I like both ketchup and pancakes but not together.

How can I say something like that idiomatically?

I want to say that two things are good but they just don't mix well together.

Comment: They don't *go together well*.

Comment: Oil and water is the usual idiom/phrase, no?

Comment: The way you said it is fine.

Comment: @vickyace In a scientific register, 'do not foodpair [well]' might be spot on, but well removed as not being all that idiomatic.

Comment: Technically, if they don't mix (eg, as oil and water don't mix) they are *immiscible*.

Comment: Pancakes and ketchup are incompatible. They have irreconcilable differences (or simply, they are irreconcilable). They constitute a wedding, but not one made in heaven. They must needs be divorced from each other. They need to agree to disagree agreeably. There ought to be a legal separation between the two.

Comment: I can assure you that there are thousands, if not millions, of kids in the US who like to put ketchup on their pancakes.

Comment: A savoury yeast pancake with a tuna, onion and ketchup filling, topped with a warm mustard sauce is the food of the gods. And thanks to this question I now know what I'll be having for supper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idiomatically, something along the lines of "mesh" would work in the place of "go together," as the word's usage as a verb according to Oxford is:

> ***[mesh](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mesh)***
>
> **1**. *[no object]* (of the teeth of a gearwheel) be engaged with another gearwheel.
>
> *‘one gear meshes with the input gear’*
>
> > **1.1** Make or become entangled or entwined.
> >
> > *[no object]* ‘their fingers meshed’
> >
> > *[with object]* ‘I don't want to get meshed in the weeds’
> >
> > **1.2** Be in or bring into harmony.
> >
> > ***[no object]* ‘her memory of events doesn't mesh with the world around her’**

In your (particularly unappealing) case, I think the second bolded verb definition would be applicable, and something along the lines of "while pancakes and ketchup are delicious on their own, they don't mesh well" would probably work. Hope this is of help!

Answer (score 2):

You can say that *pancakes and ketchup do not go well together*.

From the *Oxford English Dictionary:*

> **to go together**
>
> 2. Of two or more things: **to be mutually compatible, concomitant, or complementary**. Also of a thing: to be concomitant or concurrent *with* another.

Compare [the comment by Drew](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384782/how-to-say-that-two-things-dont-mix-well#comment906011_384782):

> They don't *go together well*.